# Search for word in file then replace text in other file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have two files. *File1* contains a Username and Password like this:

```
[reader]
label                         = anylabel
protocol                      = cccam
device                        = some.url,13377
user                          = Username1
password                      = password1
password2                     = password2
inactivitytimeout             = 30
group                         = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
cccversion                    = 2.3.2
ccckeepalive                  = 1
```

and *File2* contains a line like:

```
http://link:port/username/password/12345
```

Now I have this "code" to change the Username/Password in *File2*:

```
UsernameOLD=Username1
PasswordOLD=password1
UsernameNEW=Username2
PasswordNEW=password2

sed -i -e "s/\/$UsernameOLD\/$PasswordOLD/\/$UsernameNEW\/$PasswordNEW/" /etc/enigma2/file2.cfg
```

Now I have different Usernames which are always up to date in *File1*. I'm now searching for a solution to write the Username and the Password2 from *File1* to a variable and then set this new Username and Password in *File2*.

So as a noob the psuedocode should be something like:

```
find "username" & "password1" in file1 
set "username" as $UsernameNEW and
    "password1" as $PasswordNEW and
then just execute my sed command.
```

Can anyone assist ? I guess I could use `grep` for this? But to be honest I'm happy I got this `sed` command with variables to work :D

Comment: How many readers do you have in your OSCam server?  Should not be to many, so change user/password using webgui should be doable.

Comment: I have two its not about the readers ;) I have a lot of receivers which im all syncing with the same bouquet etc. and i have a script building the bouquet with some IPTV channels and for this i need to change user/password and that username and password is in the File1

Comment: I tried awk to get the line user and password2 but sadly there are spaces between user and the = and i dont know how to copy everything after "username ="

Comment: Some question. Config can only contain 1 passord pr user, you have 2? Do you need to change username? If yes, why?. It would be easy to lookup new password for a corresponding user, and just change the password. If you ask me, it would be simpler to just remove the user and recreate it with new username and password from a file.

Comment: This is definitely a job for awk, not grep or sed. Please [edit] your question to  clarify your requirements and show the expected output given the sample input you provided so we have something we can test a potential solution with and so can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some to get you started.

oscam.conf

```
[reader]
label                         = anylabel
protocol                      = cccam
device                        = some.url,13377
user                          = xxx1
password                      = password1
inactivitytimeout             = 30
group                         = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
cccversion                    = 2.3.2
ccckeepalive                  = 1


[reader]
label                         = anylabel
protocol                      = cccam
device                        = test.url,13377
user                          = yyy1
password                      = password1
inactivitytimeout             = 30
group                         = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
cccversion                    = 2.3.2
ccckeepalive                  = 1
```

For the password file I have changed the format some, but can be done with original format.

passwd  (format oldUser,newUser,oldPass,newUser)

```
xxx1,xxx2,passxxx1,passxxx2
yyy1,yyy2,passyyy1,passyyy2
```

Awk command

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {usr[$1]=$2;pass[$1]=$4;next} FNR!=NR{FS=" = "}  /^user/ {t=$2;$2="= "usr[$2]} /^password/ {$2="= "pass[t]} 1' passwd oscam.reader
```

result

```
[reader]
label                         = anylabel
protocol                      = cccam
device                        = some.url,13377
user                          = xxx2
password                      = passxxx2
inactivitytimeout             = 30
group                         = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
cccversion                    = 2.3.2
ccckeepalive                  = 1


[reader]
label                         = anylabel
protocol                      = cccam
device                        = test.url,13377
user                          = yyy2
password                      = passyyy2
inactivitytimeout             = 30
group                         = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
cccversion                    = 2.3.2
ccckeepalive                  = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty -- loading the old passwords into environmental parameters:

```
set -- $(grep -m1 -A1 '^user' File1)
sed -i -e "s#/${UsernameOLD}/${PasswordOLD}#/$3/$6#;T;q" /etc/enigma2/file2.cfg
```

How it works:  `grep` spews out six space separated items, which `set` turns into command line parameters `$1 $2 $3 ... $6`.  We just need `$3` and `$6`.